# How should I write a "smart" string comparison against an array of possible matches?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string from an input form and would like to compare it against a number of possible validation strings using a case-insensitive comparison, and return `true` if a match is found.

For example, if the input is `input = 'florida'` (or `'FL'`, or `'flor.'`) and I compare it against `validate = ['fl', 'florida']`, or some such validation array, it should return `true`.

I know I could use tag `select` with an explicit list of options, however, this is more of an example. In my case, the field can return multiple types of strings, so I'm trying to find a good solution to "parse". Seems like the sort of problem Ruby is good at?

Comment: what do you mean that the field can return multiple types of strings?  in your example some variation of `#include?` or `#any?` would work

Comment: Looks like you'll want `validate.any? { |word| word == input }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to compare multiple strings, especially when you can have variations on them, is to use a regular expression. Ruby has some helper methods to make this easier:

```
validate = ['fl', 'florida']

regex = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(validate.sort_by{ |s| [-s.size, s] }).source })\b/i
regex # => /\b(?:florida|fl)\b/i
'FL'[regex] # => "FL"
'florida'[regex] # => "florida"

'flor.'[regex] # => nil
```

Remember that in Ruby, only `nil` and `false` are false values, and every other result is considered true. A shortcut to force true/false values is to use `!!` (`not not`). Compare the above results with these:

```
!!'FL'[regex] # => true
!!'florida'[regex] # => true
!!'flor.'[regex] # => false
```

`'flor.'` didn't match because the pattern is looking for whole-word matches, due to the surrounding `\b` (word-boundary) markers. Removing them, or adding `flor.` to the pattern would fix that:

```
validate = ['fl', 'florida', 'flor']
regex = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(validate.sort_by{ |s| [-s.size, s] }).source })\b/i
'flor.'[regex] # => "flor"
```

`'flor.'` can't be used because of the `\b` which conflict with the trailing `.` in `flor.`. Removing `\b`:

```
validate = ['fl', 'florida', 'flor.']
regex = /(?:#{ Regexp.union(validate.sort_by{ |s| [-s.size, s] }).source })/i
'flor.'[regex] # => "flor."
```

You can get very expressive with the values in the `validate` array when passing them to `Regexp.union` but watch out for `union` escaping the contents of the string to protect characters that are special in regular expressions:

```
Regexp.union(%w[a \b dollars$ . * ? +]) # => /a|\\b|dollars\$|\.|\*|\?|\+/
```

You can control this:

```
patterns = %w[a \b dollars$ . \* \? \+]
/#{ patterns.join('|') }/ # => /a|\b|dollars$|.|\*|\?|\+/
```

Sometimes I build a pattern in several steps, other times I can do it all at once. It's something you have to experiment with.

Back to the beginning. The reason unioned patterns are faster is the regular expression engine is very fast, and the string is only searched once, even if multiple elements are OR'd (using `|`) in the pattern.

Comment: Yet to master writing of regex's -- will study & experiment -- thanks!

Comment: The important thing to learn, and know, about regex, is that they are *NOT* suited to every occasion. People start to learn them and think they're useful for everything, and they're not. Sometimes they are very powerful when using them with regularly-repeating text patterns, but other times it's much easier and faster to use `split` or `scan` to break down the string and access its parts. More complex patterns are harder to understand and maintain. They are useful though. Have fun with them!

Answer (score 1):

I usually just put the values into an array and then use the include? method, which returns true if the input matches any of the elements of the array.

```
['fl', 'florida', 'FL'].include?(input)
```

Comment: Great 'quickie'. For starters, went with: validate_array.include?(input.downcase). Thanks!